# How to use a WinRT component in c# console(windows form) app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, console

I have a c++ WinRT component, added to my console app reference. It compiles without any error, but when running app get following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find Windows Runtime type
>   'ProcessorInfoComponent.ProcessorInfoProvider'.
>   [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prLRn.jpg)

This is my code:

.h file :

```
#pragma once

namespace ProcessorInfoComponent
{
public ref class ProcessorInfoProvider sealed
{
   public:
      bool IsNeonSupported();
};
}
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "ProcessorInfoComponent.h"
using namespace ProcessorInfoComponent;

bool ProcessorInfoProvider::IsNeonSupported()
{
     return IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_ARM_VFP_32_REGISTERS_AVAILABLE);
}
```

and using in c# is:
.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        var processorInfoProvider = new ProcessorInfoComponent.ProcessorInfoProvider();

        var isNeonSupported = processorInfoProvider.IsNeonSupported();

        Console.WriteLine(isNeonSupported);

    }
```

this WinRT work very well in windows phone and WPF APP but in windows form and console app not work.
thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference, you should read up on the MSDN page for `TypeLoadException` and you should put a `try...catch(Exception ex)` around where the error is occuring and look at the `ex.message`, generally a good way to catch any errors that might be occuring.

In terms of the error you are having, I'm pretty sure that you aren't able to mix WinRT and WinForms/Console apss since they execute in different ways and WinRT is limited, meaning it doesn't include .Net Framework so can't use many of the functions used in WinForms.

Also, the reason it compiles properly is because of the way C# compiles and runs programs. The C# compiler compiles the code into a `Module` and then into `assembly` which contains an `Intermediate Language` and some `Metadata`. In short, the program compiles because of no syntax errors but hits a runtime error when executing the line `var processorInfoProvider = new ProcessorInfoComponent.ProcessorInfoProvider();`.

Check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) website for some more info on how WinRT works.
Or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/compilation-process-of-a-c-sharp-program1) website for some more info on the C# Compiler.

Hope this helps.